# Old Disk Size Showing in Explorer

Tags: iscsi, dell-equallogic

We recently added a second iSCSI disk array to an existing disk array group. This added 6TB to our pool. In the pool we have 3 volumes. I added 2TB of free space to each of the 3 volumes.

If I login to one of the servers with the iSCSI targets configured I see C:\ClusterStorage. In that directory we have Volume1, Volume2, and Volume3.

Under the Size column each shows the old capacity (1.5 TB) instead of 3.5TB.

I have already allocated the 2TB to each volume in the Dell Equal Logic Group Manager and confirmed the capacity is 3.5TB.

Is there anything I need to do for the servers attached to the iSCSI volumes to identify the correct Volume capacities?

Comment: You need to increase the size of the formatted volume under disk management.

Comment: I didn't realize that also applied to iSCSI volumes too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the size of the formatted volume under disk management.